# Gree Implementation with Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

(Part that you can give up if you want to go straight to the question)
I took several hours to success the OpenFeint implementation few months ago. Too bad, OpenFeint has been bought for 104Mo$, and I have to remake everything. Since I've created a random test account in OpenFeint, and create new accounts isn't possible anymore, I'm trapped!

(Actual question)
Well, does anybody reach to implement Gree on a basic Cocos2d Sample app? And how does the GameCenter implementation work with Gree now?
I've already checked this blog: http://www.mostafaberg.com/2012/06/how-to-add-gree-to-your-ios-game/ , it has helped me a bit but not enough to succeed!

Comment: If you could ask a more specific question you're more likely to get answers. Tell us where you're stuck, what's the actual problem you're having right now that prevents you from using it? Where exactly does the tutorial stop being helpful?

Comment: Well. What are the functions to use in the AppDelegate to set up Gree?  How to call the Gree First Use Splashscreen? LeaderBoards? Achievements?
Does the achievements are stocked in a .plist like OpenFeint? 
What about GameCenter? Is it always as easy as it was with OpenFeint?

Comment: From now, I've added the SDK's "source" and "ressource" folders to my app and this this to the AppDelegate.m: 

     `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
     The Ns Dictionnary (Too long to post here)

    [GreePlatform initializeWithApplicationId:@"XXXX" consumerKey:@"XXXXXXXX" consumerSecret:@"XXXXXXXXX" settings:settings delegate:self];
 
    [GreePlatform authorize];
    
    [GreePlatform handleLaunchOptions:launchOptions application:application];`

With the good values of course, but all I get is plenty of errors!

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who's stuck with Gree and Cocos2d:

http://www.mostafaberg.com/2012/08/integrating-gree-into-your-cocos2d-game/